# php function coded default parameter num

Tags: php, parameters

In PHP, is it possible to get the coded parameter count?

Something like this(pseudo code):

```
function($a=false , $b=true){ //the $a=true... is just parameters, with default values
  echo func_num_args();
  echo ", ";
  echo func_get_coded_params(); //how do i do this in PHP?
}

echo function(1 , 2); // output -> 2, 2 

echo function(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, a, b, c); // output -> 8, 2
```

Is there an way/imaginary function(`func_get_coded_params()`) that can retrieve the default coded parameter count?
In this case, the coded parameters would be $a and $b itself which returns 2.
If i do `function($a, $b, $c)` it would return 3

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's constant in every function.

Comment: You shouldn't have $a and $b there if you using func_num_args() or func_get_args()

Comment: i still need my default parameters in my function, so that's why i need $a and $b and vars like that

Comment: I'm still not quite sure why you would need such a function, as it is a constant in a function.

Comment: Could you give example with outputs like `2, 1` or `3, 0` ?

Comment: @galymzhan 2, 1 => function foo($a) gets called like foo(1, 2) ; 3, 0 => function foo() gets called like foo(a, b, c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ReflectionFunction`](https://www.php.net/ReflectionFunction) and call the  [`getNumberOfParameters`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofparameters.php)  method.

You can create an instance of the current function using:

```
$func = new ReflectionFunction(__FUNCTION__);
```

And get the number of defined parameters using

```
$func->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
```

**Edit**

For use in classes.

```
$func = new ReflectionMethod(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__);
```

Comment: wait, what if i want to do this in  __construct()? i tried to put this in construct and an exception is raised saying __construct() is not found...

Comment: For inside a class you will need to use [`ReflectionMethod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) instead. `new ReflectionMethod(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__);`

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a number of useful `Reflection` classes you can use.

```
function whatever($a, $b, $c)
{
  $reflection = new ReflectionFunction(__FUNCTION__);
  echo func_num_args() . ', ' .  $reflection->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
}

whatever(1,2,3,4,5); // Prints 5, 3
```

Check http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.reflectionfunction.php

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need:

```
class x
{
    function __construct($a=1,$b=2)
    {

        $constructor = new ReflectionMethod(__CLASS__,__FUNCTION__);
        $params = $func->getNumberOfParameters();
        echo func_num_args().",".$params;
    }
}
$x = new x(1,2,3,4); //output -> 4,2
```

Note that since you are having default values defined for your arguments in the constructor, what you need to call is `getNumberOfParameters()` and not `getNumberOfRequiredParameters()` (because there are no required parameters, they all have default values)